# How to set the width of a table column?

Tags: swt, column-width

I am trying to set the Width of the columns in the code bellow but it does not change. What is wrong with this code?

```java
    table_2 = new Table(shell, SWT.CHECK | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.SINGLE | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    table_2.setBounds(321, 47, 85, 98);

    table_2.setLinesVisible(true);
    TableColumn tbl2_tc1 = new TableColumn(table_2,SWT.NONE);
    TableColumn tbl2_tc2 = new TableColumn(table_2,SWT.NONE);
    tbl2_tc1.setWidth(120);
    tbl2_tc1.pack();
    tbl2_tc2.setWidth(40);
    tbl2_tc2.pack();
    table_2.pack();
```

Comment: Probably the TableColumn.pack calls which override the set width.

Answer (score 2):

Don't call `TableColumn.pack()` as that resets the column size to the 'preferred size' - which is not the one you set with `setWidth`.